# two processes call open, one "W", another "r" at the same time. Error happens?

Tags: c, gcc, fopen

Suppose I have a process call A which call fopen(filename,"w"); every second, and write data in it, while process B call fopen(filename,"r") every 0.2 second and read data from it !!

In a very seldom situation, while A is writing data , before A fclose it, B process do fopen and read data from it. I think it has a sync problem!

Using Mutex is easy in thread, but I haven't tried mutex between processes. The data is only 400 bytes at most, I'd like to know what is the easy way to avoid a process writing data, and another process reading at the same time, or, while one process A fopen a file, another process B would wait until the process A fclose the file!

Comment: Wait... It is the same file each time, or different files?

Comment: If the file is used solely as a means for the two processes to talk to each other, then your should probably consider a different form of inter-process communication (e.g. pipes, sockets, etc)

Comment: Thanks ,It is always the same file ...for both processes , and actually I've Process A to be a socket server and don't like talk to process B by socket again , so I'd like to use another way except for socket ....  pipe is option to me , if process B talk to process A by pipe , if Process B die suddently , it will cause broken pipe of process A , Process A as a important socket server , I don't like process A die because a little process B , I just need a safe way to let process A to get a little data from process B , even just every 5 second to get data from process B would be fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* use files (as @aix has said, there may be better ways), don't try to read files as they are being written or the results will be undefined.

Instead, write the data to a different filename, close it, and then move it to the right place (on Linux, use `rename()`).

If you don't like that, try using file locks. On Linux, at least, these don't actually prevent access to the file, they just act as inter-process mutexes. You don't say what OS you have, but for Linux, see `man 2 flock`.

Comment: Thanks , I use linux , so if process B write to a file b1.txt and move to another file b2.txt , and process A read b2.txt , that will be ok ? what if process B is moving to b2.txt while process A try to read b2.txt at the same time ? I'll try to understand flock , thank you for your kind help !!

Comment: From `man 2 rename`: `rename()  renames  a  file,  moving it between directories if required.  Any other hard links to the file (as created using link(2))  are  unaffected.  Open file descriptors for oldpath are also unaffected.  If  newpath already exists it will be atomically replaced (subject to blah blah blah), so that there is no point  at  which another process attempting to access newpath will find it missing.`